# Preprocessing image before OCR

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, tesseract

I'm trying to preprocess a sample image:

[image: sample image]

before passing it to an OCR engine.

It's full of noise and I'm interested in the strings (ARS,0-1,TOT,04:02)

I was trying a few approaches:
first i scaled the image by 300% so it will be easier, next I was applying grayscale to clear as much as noise as I can.

a. adaptive thresholding

b. Stroke width transform

c. canny edges

In some cases I was able to read the string ARS (using thresholding of 127)  and in some the strings 04:02 (the SWT helped with that)

I'm a total newbie to computer vision and trying to learn as much as I can about techniques to clear noises and make it easier for the OCR engine (tesseract) to get read strings

Comment: Do those images always have the same structure? Are the team names, score and the time always in the same position? Do the text fragments have the same background color?

Comment: Hi, the structure is the same, the position is the same, the colors might be different (this is where thresholding should be helpful so we can 'clear noise')

Comment: The I would split the images into different parts and process them separately. Then you could apply better targeted image preprocessing and you could also restrict the expected characters (number or alpha) for the single parts.

Comment: Yes, thats what i'm trying, i'm really a newbie so I'm still reading about filtering by colors (especially gradients) so I can filter each string by its color